# Linux Mint 20.1 (Cinnamon) is randomly hanging/freezing for one sec on ThinkPad X1 Yoga (3rd Gen)

Tags: linux-mint, thinkpad, hang

My Mint 20.1 is randomly freezing/hanging for about one second without any obvious reason. That's what I was observing:

- It occurs every 2 - 5 Minutes
- There is no system overload, <5% CPU <20% RAM
- It happens everywhere (Web, Media, Office...)
- Video is hanging, Sound not
- It's every time, also after reboot

Here is my system Info: https://termbin.com/z25l

Eveyting is up-to-date and just "fresh" installed

Comment: The System info includes: `Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 482.54 GiB (101.2%)` - this seems a bit mysterious.

Comment: right! I reinstalled my system completely. Now there are no Windows-Partitions anymore, just Mint 20.1 - The problem is still the same as described. I updated the termbin: https://termbin.com/z25l